# Elegant way to repeat something at intervals in a regularly called function

Tags: loops, time, language-agnostic, intervals

I regularly write software that uses a framework in which a callback method is called many times per second, but inside that callback I only want to do some operation every `N` seconds.  So I do this a lot:

```
int lastMethodCallTime = 0;
int methodRunIntervalMs = 5000;
void methodThatGetsCalledManyTimesPerSecond(){
   int currentTime = getCurrentTime();
   if(currentTime - lastMethodCallTime >= methodRunIntervalMs){
      lastMethodCallTime = currentTime;
      myMethod();
   }
}
```

But gross.  That is ugly, requires declaring external variables and is very bug prone (many a times I have forgotten the `lastMethodCallTime = currentTime;` and then wondering why it was called so many times).  And if you have multiple methods that get called at different intervals then this ugliness just multiplies.

Surely there's a more elegant way?  I'm looking for an idea that I can implement in any language.  Also, in many cases putting the method call into a separate thread isn't an option, so I need to work within those constraints.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not very general. I am providing a suggestion in Java, and you may see whether you can adapt it to other languages you are using. I am using some Java features.

Also I cannot write your code more beautifully than what you have already done. My suggestion is to apply something that Bjarne Stroustrup wrote: code can be as ugly as it needs to be as long as you can hide it behind a nice interface. This would allow you to write your example code like this:

```
CallFrequencyController myCallFrequencyController
        = new CallFrequencyController(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, this::myMethod);

void methodThatGetsCalledManyTimesPerSecond() {
    myCallFrequencyController.call();
}
```

This is where I am hiding the ugly code:

```
class CallFrequencyController {

    Instant nextCallTime = Instant.now();
    final long methodRunIntervalNanos;
    final Runnable methodToCall;

    public CallFrequencyController(int frequency, TimeUnit frequencyUnit, Runnable methodToCall) {
        methodRunIntervalNanos = frequencyUnit.toNanos(frequency);
        this.methodToCall = methodToCall;
    }

    public void call() {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        if (now.isBefore(nextCallTime)) {
            return;
        }

        methodToCall.run();

        nextCallTime = now.plusNanos(methodRunIntervalNanos);
    }

}
```

You can develop this class once and test it thoroughly, and then you need no longer worry about forgetting to update the last or next call time or writing other bugs.

If you need to pass an argument to `myMethod` and return a result from it to your framework, you will need your class to be generic. It’s a further complication, but again: it’s mostly hidden behind a nice interface. Yes, the interface is generic, but that’s nice, and in particular the code using it looks nice. The complication is hidden behind it.